# Dynamic AJAX content for p:commandButton click JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to add new text boxes when a `<p:commandButton>` button clicked. 
But when I try to update the view I'm getting the following error in the eclipse console.

```
ERROR [ServletExternalContextImpl] Cannot set content type. Response already committed
```

Appreciate any help on this.

When I click the Edit link it should get the values from an ArrayList in the the bean.

```
 <p:commandLink value="Edit" style="font-size:small!important;"
                    immediate="false" update=":company:editPremisesDlg" rendered="true"                 
                    action="#{registerBean.editPremisesAction(premises)}" 
                    oncomplete="editPremisesDlg.show()"/>
```

Server Code:

```
public String editPremisesAction(Premises premises) {
    System.out.println("******"+premises.portableWaterAccounts.size());
    selectedPremisesIndex = this.company.premisesList.indexOf(premises);
    this.selectedPremises = new Premises(premises); 
    WaterAccountBean waterAccountBean=(WaterAccountBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
    getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("waterAccountBean");
    List<UIComponent> pwChildren=waterAccountBean.getEditPwPanel().getChildren();
    //assign values for water accounts
    for(int i=0;i<pwChildren.size();i++)
    {
        UIComponent uiComponent=pwChildren.get(i);
        if(uiComponent instanceof HtmlInputText)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" #####");
            if(i<premises.getPwWaterAccounts().size()-1)
            {


                ((HtmlInputText) uiComponent).setValue(premises.getPwWaterAccounts().get(i));
                System.out.println("******"+premises.getPwWaterAccounts().get(i));
                ((HtmlInputText) uiComponent).setStyleClass("showview");

            }
            else
            {
                ((HtmlInputText) uiComponent).setValue("");
                ((HtmlInputText) uiComponent).setStyleClass("hideview");
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Display view :

```
<h:panelGroup  cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  id="editPanelPW" binding="#{waterAccountBean.editPwPanel}">
                <h:inputText  id="editPw0" required="false"
                    style="width:325px;" maxlength="100" />
<h:inputText  id="editPw1" required="false"
                    style="width:325px;" maxlength="100" />


                </h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandButton  value="Add New" type="button" onclick="showNewInput('pw')">

                </p:commandButton>
```

Appreciate if you could suggest me the best way to add dynamic content (for example adding textboxes to a panel when a button is clicked) to a JSF page. Currently I used some javascript to do that. But is there any pure JSF way to add mulitple text boxes dynamically and bind them to an ArrayList in a managed bean? Thanks.

Comment: And is it possible to see the code you have?

Comment: post you server and front end code